# How to get current locale's negative sign character on Mac/iOS

Tags: ios, macos, nsnumberformatter

Do you happen to know how to get current locale's negative sign character on Mac/iOS?

Comment: Have you ever saw a negative sign other than `-`?

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf While I don't know of any locales that have something other than "a partial horizontal line" as their minus sign, many locales use MINUS SIGN (U+2212) which is generally rendered quite a bit wider and higher than the more common HYPHEN-MINUS (U+002D). Compare: -2 vs −2. Right-to-left languages often have explicit directional indicators as well, since - is non-directional in Unicode. In locales that use Arabic script, some  place the sign on the right, and some place it on the left (it's a prefix in either case; just marked with different directionality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSNumberFormatter.negativePrefix` returns the prefix for negative numbers. There are also related `positivePrefix`, `negativeSuffix`, and `positiveSuffix`.

Note that this may not be a single character. In the standard Arabic locale ("ar"), for instance, it is RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK followed by HYPHEN-MINUS.

Comment: Thank you so much. really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

OSX implements POSIX locales with a few extensions.  This would be in the *`LC_NUMERIC`* category, but is not mentioned in [`localedef(1)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/localedef.1.html):

> Defines the decimal delimiter, grouping, and grouping symbol for non-monetary numeric editing.

However, it *is* a feature returned by the `localconv` function (and is mentioned in the POSIX document for [`localeconv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/localeconv.html)):

> **`negative_sign`**
>   The character used to denote negative currency values, usually a minus sign.

You would retrieve this information by first initializing the locale using `setlocale`, and then calling `localeconv`.

Further reading:

- [setlocale -- natural language formatting for C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/setlocale.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/setlocale)
- [localeconv, localeconv_l -- natural language formatting for C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/localeconv.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/localeconv)